# How to wait for a tag not to contain attribute using protractor

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I have an element which has attribute disabled='disabled'. How can i wait, until element stop having that attribute at all, not to be changed on 'enabled', but just not having that attribute at all anymore.

I am checking on attribute value like this:

```
el.getAttribute('disabled').then(function (atr) {
                    expect(atr).toMatch('disabled');
                });
```

Now i need to wait for a condition, when this attribute disappear, but didn't find any suitable solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the expected condition `elementToBeClickable`. It will wait for the element to be displayed and not disabled:

```javascript
var EC = ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element), 5000);
```

Comment: There are other types of `ExpectedConditions`. It doesn't have to be just `elementToBeClickable`, there is also, for example, `visiblilityOf`. See http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions for more info.

Answer (score -3):

You can use `browser.sleep(6000);`